# QTP - Determine whether to continue with action or not

Tags: testing, vbscript, automation, automated-tests

I am like a week into automation testing and I have an issue that I need help with..

What I have is the following (Action Names):

*Open Application*

*Login*

*Find Accommodation*

*Select Accommodation*

*Confirm Booking*

**Search**

**Search Results**

**Booking Details**

*Close Application*

The 3 actions in bold above is where my issue is.

In the 'Search' page of the application, you can either search by name or by booking number.

If you search by name, you're taken to the 'Search Results' page and presented with a DataGrid where you need to select your booking and click on next, then you go to the 'Booking Details' page

If you search by number, you're immediately taken to the 'Booking Details' page

Now with the actions, the order - whether you choose name or number search - is

Search

Search Results

Booking Details

So I am trying to figure out a way of how I can 'skip' the 'Search Results' action when I search by number.

I'm sure it will be some form of an if statement, but I am not that familiar with  the UFT tool yet and perhaps there is a way of doing it with UFT?

Even if I use an if statement, I do not know what my condition criteria would be. Any help will be appreciated.

***UPDATE:***

There are two radio buttons on the Search page, so you select whichever one you're going to use and enter either a name or number in their respective text fields, then click on the 'Search' button.

I pull the search criteria from an excel sheet and the below If Statement will check if the value is null, if it is, it gets the value in the next cell and by default that would be a name search. If the value is not null, it checks if it is a number, if it is, it will select the radio button to search by booking number.

Perhaps within this If Statement can be a condition that decides which action to go to next?

***Code:***

```
'Find the tab that is called 'SEARCH BOOKING' and select it
WpfWindow("Application").WpfTabStrip("WpfTabStrip").Select "SEARCH BOOKING"

'Import selected Excel spreadsheet - PATH, SOURCE SHEET, DESTINATION SHEET
DataTable.ImportSheet "PATH","SOURCE SHEET","DESTINATION SHEET" 

'Assign the value in the first row of the DataTable with the header 'Booking_Number' to a variable
x = DataTable.LocalSheet.GetParameter("Booking_Number").Value

'Check if the variable is empty
If x = "" Then

    'If it is empty, get the value of the cell in the first row with the header 'Guest' and assign it to the variable
    x = DataTable.LocalSheet.GetParameter("Guest").Value

    'Take the value of the variable and paste it in the text field named 'byNameWatermark'
    WpfWindow("Application").WpfEdit("byNameWatermark").Set DataTable("Guest", dtLocalSheet)

    'Find a button named 'SEARCH' and click on it
    WpfWindow("Application").WpfButton("SEARCH").Click

'If the initial variable is not empty
Else

    'Check if the 'char' is a number
    If ( isnumeric(x) = True) Then

        'Select the radio button called 'byNumberRadio'
        WpfWindow("Application").WpfRadioButton("byNumberRadio").Set

        'Take the value of the variable and paste it in the text field named 'byNumberWatermark'
        WpfWindow("Application").WpfEdit("byNumberWatermark").Set DataTable("Booking_Number", dtLocalSheet)

        'Find a button named 'SEARCH' and click on it
        WpfWindow("Application").WpfButton("SEARCH").Click  

    End If        

End If
```

Comment: You could have a check at the start of `Search Results` action that checks if the `Search` action ran with a number search and if so carries out an `Exit Action` statement to move onto the next action

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the reply, I will need to do a little more research on how to do what you suggested. Although, on the Search page I have an if statement that determines whether to search by number or search by name (it is extracted from a DataTable) - I have updated above

Comment: look up the `RunAction` command in the UFT help - you should be able to call the `Booking Details` action directly from your `IF` statement

Comment: @Dave I had this in the Search Results action - RunAction "Booking Details", oneIteration -  I have now put it into the Search action under the isNumeric if statement, but what happens is that after it has run through Booking Details action, it continues executing the Search Results action - It's almost like all it is doing pushing the Order Details action before the Search Results but then it continues with the default execution of the actions

Comment: Presumably the script is set up to execute each action once, in which case you will need to add the check to the Search Results action as I originally suggested - `If IsNumeric(DataTable("Booking_Number")) Then ExitAction` which will cause the Search Results action to exit and move onto the Order Details one?

Comment: Note that without sight of your data table values I'm blindly guessing at the `IF` construction being sufficient that the value is populated and numeric to determine that the search was done by Booking Number...

Comment: @Dave Okay perfect, I will research more :) Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a radio button to select searchbyName or searchbybookingid

The logic for that would be something like..

```
If(control(searchbyName).getROProperty("enabled")) Then 
    ' go with search results page and then click on booking number
Else
    'directly you will get booking details
End if
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I do apologize, the question was worded poorly. I have provided an update above..